# pysimplegui, show selected part of a table

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have a small database with ~9000 rows. Every time I start my program the table starts with the 1:st row.
Is it possible to programatically show a specific part of the table, like show last records or show records adjacent to for examle row 1172?
/p-a

Comment: That should be possible, yes, but it may depend of what type of database you are working with. Can you provide some more info?

Comment: @Kjartan. Thanks for your comment. I dont think its database related but for your info I use PostgreSql on a Linux computer. I seems to me that it has something to do with how PuSimpleGUI implements the table (not the database table but PySimpleGUI.Table(...). I cant find any table cmd in PysimpleGUI documentation that let me do what I want...

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the rows you do not want to show ('iid' is a unique identifier of the row assigned when you add the row to the table:

```
tkTable = window['~TABLE~'].Widget

new_row = 'some text'
tkTable.insert('', 'end', iid=id, text='some text', values=new_row)

tkTable.detach(iid)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `see` of widget, arguments is the row number which count from 0. It maybe on the bottom line in your shown area.

```py
...
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalized)
window['-TABLE-'].Widget.see(1172)
...
```